# Rails + Angular + sqlite3 Deployment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, angularjs, heroku, sqlite

I'm a beginner for this and currently finding a free web host and has a couple of questions.

- Will **Heroku** be able to handle all of this: **AngularJS**, **Ruby on Rails**, and **sqlite3**?
- What are other good free web hosts? This is just for a personal portfolio/blog.

I'm seeing several tutorials in the internet and just like to have the simplest one.

If it helps, my root/home page is at *app>views>application>application.html.erb* and I don't have an index.html. I also develop on Windows 8.1.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: sqlite is not supported by heroku

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Rails to serve the API to the Angular-powered frontend in your app, there shouldn't be a problem with Heroku hosting your app. Here is a [live example](https://young-fortress-5170.herokuapp.com/posts) of an Angular/Rails app being hosted on Heroku.

**However**, Heroku does not support SQLite.

> While easy to use, SQLite is not intended as a production grade database. Instead Heroku provides production grade PostgreSQL databases as a service.
>
> [- SQLite on Heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/sqlite3)

The article above shows you how to configure your app from using SQLite to Postgres, which Heroku supports.

---

**Note:** It's *always* a good idea to have the same database setup for both your development and production environments. However, if you're starting out and building a very simple application, and want to quickly get started with Heroku, there's another option below:

If you want to continue using SQLite3 in development, you can leave your `sqlite3` gem in your `:development` group, and add the `pg` gem to the `:production` group in the app's Gemfile:

```
group :development do
  gem 'sqlite3'
  ...
end

group :production do 
  gem 'pg'
  gem 'rails_12factor'
  ...
end
```

And then set up your `config/database.yml` file accordingly (sqlite for development/test, postgres in production):

```
development:
  adapter: sqlite3
  database: db/development.sqlite3
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000

production:
  adapter: postgres
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000
```

This way you wouldn't need to install/configure Postgres locally if you only want to make a simple application to host on Heroku.

Hope this helped!

Comment: Cool. But can I switch from SQLite3 to PostgreSQL now? I still don't have data in it. Just several tables I always clean up. I'm using RubyMine and initialized my app to have SQLite3.

Comment: You can definitely switch over. You would have to install PostgreSQL on your local machine and modify your config/database.yml adapters to use postgres. If you want to keep using SQLite, I have updated my answer with another option.

Comment: No, man. Will be switching now so that on both development and production I'll have a common database. I'll follow what the instructions on the link you gave (https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/sqlite3) on switching. Really helpful! Thank you!

Comment: Yeah it's def a good idea for your dev/production environments to be as close to each other as possible. Glad it was helpful!